# Using Amazon S3 for iOS app storing images / audio files

Tags: ios, image, audio, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to AWS services, so forgive the simple question:

I'm building an iOS app that is currently using RDS and EC2 instances. I now want to store photos and audio files in an S3 bucket. I know there is an iOS SDK which makes it easy to download from and upload to an S3 bucket directly from the iOS side. However, should I also be using Cloudfront to decrease latency in addition? What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently built an app that moved photos back and forth between S3. I looked into using Amazon's SDK but it was just too bulky.

Instead I used Matt Thompson's [AFAmazonS3Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Manager).

Worth looking into if you are building an app with AWS.

Comment: is there a way to manipulate image dimensions or cropping the image when using the AFAmazonS3Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. You should use cloudfront if you need to reduce latency, and especially if your users a spread out all over the globe - cloudfront will help with that.

On the otherhand, there is an extra cost in using it (sometimes substantial), so if you are not having a latency problem, why bother?

If you decide you need cloudfront, it is extraordinarily easy to add in.